# Не получается считать данные из потока ввода

Tags: c++

Не получается считать данные из потока cin в вектор age, в функции read_ages().

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Name_pairs {
public:
    void read_names();
    void read_ages();
    void print();
    void sort();
private:
    vector<string> name;
    vector<double> age;
};

void Name_pairs::read_names()
{
    string temp;

    cout << "Пожалуйста, введите имена\n";

    while (cin >> temp)
        name.push_back(temp);
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages()
{
    double temp;

    cout << "Пожалуйста, введите возраст для:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
        cout << name[i] << endl;

    while (cin >> temp)
        age.push_back(temp);
}

void Name_pairs::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
        cout << name[i] << " " << age[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Name_pairs names;

    names.read_names();
    names.read_ages();
    //names.print();
}
```

Программа не выдает приглашение ко вводу, а просто завершается без ошибок. Использую компилятор gcc.

Comment: А у меня почему-то выдаёт. Что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: ТС о приглашении к вводу возраста, а не имен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

логично. Как Ваша программа узнает, что имена закончились? как? Я бы к примеру, сделал так - если введено пустое имя или "специмя", то значит, что имена закончились.

```
void Name_pairs::read_names()
{
    string temp;
    cout << "Пожалуйста, введите имена" << std::endl;
    while (getline(cin, temp)) {
        if (temp == "") break;
        name.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

read_ages страдает этой же болезнью.

```
void Name_pairs::read_ages()
{
    double temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Пожалуйста, введите возраст для: ";
        cout << name[i] << endl;

        cin >> temp;
        age.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

теперь, когда все имена будут введены, нужно будет просто дважды нажать enter.

Comment: Хоть проблема заключалась и не совсем в этом, все же вы натолкнули меня на решение. Проблема была в том, что я прекращал ввод имен символом конца файла (ctrl-d), и функция read_ages(), судя по-всему, встречая этот символ отказывалась считывать данные из потока cin.

Comment: @some_guy, видите ли, важно правильно описывать свою проблему (достаточно полно: что Вы вводите, что хотите увидеть, **какая ОС** и т.д.).

Думаю, при правильной постановке вопроса Вам тут же подсказали бы, что достаточно написать

    cin.clear();

перед вызовом `names.read_ages();`

Comment: ctrl+d закрывает ввод. Поэтому и не даст ввести.

@avp 

    cin.clear();

не поможет.

Comment: @KoVadim, а у меня работает


    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    Begin: sjsjs
    1: sjsjs
    kskss
    1: kskss
    Continue: ueuueu
    2: ueuueu
    djsjdj
    2: djsjdj
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat tttx.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
      string t;
    
      cout << "Begin: ";
      while (cin >> t) 
        cout << "1: " << t << '\n';
      cin.clear();
      cout << "Continue: ";  
      while (cin >> t) 
        cout << "2: " << t << '\n';
    
      return 0;
    }

Comment: интересно, нужно будет подумать об этом на досуге.